# How can I pass option options to Roslyn's Formatter.Format method?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I can see that the Format method accepts option but I cant figure out how to create the OptionsSet object. One behavior in particular I'd like to change if possible is when comments occur on two consecutive line, the formatter will line them up. So

```
int x = 0; // Comment 1
// Comment 2
int y = 0;
```

becomes

```
int x = 0; // Comment 1
           // Comment 2
int y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Options` property](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Workspace.cs,194) of your Workspace.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. So would I type something like workspace = workspace.Options.WithChangedOption(FormattingOptions.IndentationSize, "C#", 4) to set an option? Do you know what is the correct way to specify C# as the language?

Comment: @Shane: `LanguageNames.CSharp`